# Django object "lock" and context rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-context

I have a simple(I think) question, about Django context rendering.

I'll step right into it -

Basically what I need is, some temp table, which in my case, I called Locked. And when a user presses a button, which Is a form, that object goes straight to the table Locked(just a simple insert). And inside that table there is a field called is_locked, and if its True, that object needs to go gray, or to have some lock icon inside the html table.

Just some kind of a viewable sign, that an object is inside the table Locked, and that another user can't access it.

But, my problem is, since in my views.py, my **lock** function is not returning exact html where I want to render that locker icon, instead, it returns another html.

Is there any way, to render same context, on 2 html pages? Thank's.

This is my code :

```
views.py


def lock(request, pk):
    # Linking by pk.
    opp = get_object_or_404(OpportunityList, pk=pk)
    opp_locked = get_object_or_404(Locked, pk=pk)
    # Taking two parametters for 2 fields.
    eluid = Elementiur.objects.get(eluid=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    # Dont bother with this one! Just pulling one field value.
    field_name = 'optika_korisnik'
    obj = OpportunityList.objects.get(pk=pk)
    field_object = OpportunityList._meta.get_field(field_name)
    field_value = getattr(obj, field_object.attname)

    # This is the main part! This is where i'm inserting data into Locked table.
    if opp_locked.DoesNotExist:
        opp_locked.id = int(eluid.eluid)
        opp_locked.locked_eluid = eluid
        opp_locked.locked_comment = field_value
        opp_locked.locked_user = user
        opp_locked.locked_name = 'Zaključao korisnik - ' + request.user.username
        opp_locked.is_locked = True
        opp_locked.save()
        # This is what has to be returned, but i need context on the other page.
        return render(request, 'opportunity/detalji/poziv.html',
                      {'opp': opp, 'locked': opp_locked})
    else:
        # This return has the context that i need(from the first opp_locked variable)
        return render(request, 'opportunity/opp_optika.html', {'locked_test': opp_locked})
```

I can provide more code, but i think that it's not important for this type of question, because all of the logic is happening inside the *lock* finction, and last two returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i got no answers, i added a new field, is_locked, into my Locked model and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a quick overview of your snippet sorry if this not help you but you need to review it a little bit.

You call `DoesNotExist` on an instance of a Locked model 
`if opp_locked.DoesNotExist: [...]`
that's not how you should use [this exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/exceptions/).

You have a method `.exists()` that is available but only for `Querysets`.

Also if your instance does not exists you are alredy returning an `Http404` response when you use `get_object_or_404()` method.

And perhaps you should avoid sharing primary keys between instances and replace them with `models.OneToOneField` ([OneToOnefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/))

Comment: Hmm .. thanks, but, that's not solving my question :( 
Do you have better idea of how should i write this?